# Why am getting booted straight to Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, 18.04

I dual booted ubuntu and then restarted my pc but instead of showing the grub bootloader menu it loads me directly into Ubuntu i do have all the files of windows including the C rom..

i tried upgrading Grub but it cant find windows 10.. WHY??
i have a gygabyte motherboard

.

Comment: can you add outputs of `sudo update-grub` and `gedit /etc/default/grub` to your Question?

Answer (score 1):

Ok fixed my issue i changed my storage boot option and other pci device ROM priority both to UEFI only and enabled LAN PXE Boot option ROM and then updated grub and rebooted my pc and it got fixed

Comment: Thanks for removing the solution from the question and posting it as an answer instead. Here we ["accept" the most useful answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick (✓) next to it) to indicate we've found a working solution and also so that others may more easily find it in the future. But since you posted the answer yourself, you won't be able to accept the answer *right now*. You'll be able to do that after two days.

Comment: Please copy/paste this answer and post it as an answer to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/. It's a question that was viewed
69,319 times, and it would help Ask Ubuntu users if they could read it there.